# Python XML to dictionary to iterate over items

Tags: python, xml

I have the following XML example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>
    <items>
        <item>item 1</item>
        <item>item 2</item>
    </items>
</test>
```

I need to iterate over each  tag in a for loop in python. If tried many things but I just can't get it..

thanks for the help

Comment: Please show some of the things you have tried.

Comment: I have tried http://github.com/joestump/python-simplexml/blob/master/simplexml.py  but if there is only 1 item it won't iterate just ends in an endless loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally use [`xml.etree.cElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), as I've found it works really well, it's fast, [easy to use](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html), and [works well with big (>2GB) files](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/).

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

with open(xml_file_path) as xml_file:
    tree = etree.iterparse(xml_file)
    for items in tree:
        for item in items:
            print item.text
```

In the interactive console

```
>>> x="""<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>
    <items>
        <item>item 1</item>
        <item>item 2</item>
    </items>
</test>"""
>>> x
'<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<test>\n    <items>\n        <item>item 1</item>\n        <item>item 2</item>\n    </items>\n</test>'
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(x)
>>> tree
<Element 'test' at 0xb63ad248>
>>> for i in tree:
        for j in i:
            print j


<Element 'item' at 0xb63ad2f0>
<Element 'item' at 0xb63ad338>
>>> for i in tree:
        for j in i:
            j.text

'item 1'
'item 2'
>>>
```

Comment: First example doesnt work. should be: '''with open(xml_file_path) as xml_file:
    tree = etree.iterparse(xml_file)
    for _,test in tree:
        for items in test:
            for item in items:
                print item.text'''

Answer (score 1):

Try xml parser from `xml.sax` package in standard library.

```
from xml.sax import parse
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler
from sys import argv

class Handler(ContentHandler):
    def startElementNS(self, name, qname, attrs):
        self.startElement(name, attrs)

    def endElementNs(self, name, qname):
        self.endElement(name, attrs)

    def startElement(self, name, qname, attrs):
        ... do whatever you like on tag start...

    def characters(self, content):
        ... on tag content ...

    def endElement(self, name):
        ... on tag closing ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse(argv[1], Handler())
```

Here I assumed argv[1] is a path to the file you'd like to parse. (first argument to parse() function is filename or stream). It is easy to convert it to for loop: just grab all the information you need in the methods above and push them into some list or stack. Iterate over it once you have finished parsing.

Answer (score 1):

```
import xml.dom.minidom as md

x='''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>
    <items>
        <item>item 1</item>
        <item>item 2</item>
    </items>
</test>
'''

xml=md.parseString(x)

items=xml.getElementsByTagName("item")
# [<DOM Element: item at 0xc16e40>, <DOM Element: item at 0xc16ee0>]
```

since `items` is DOM Element Array, you could loop with `for`

Answer (score 0):

You would probably like to use something like [ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm) This is a well renowned library, I have not personally used it but I always hear good things.

Also as of python 2.5 it's part of the standard library